# Is the Kronecker sum an affine transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, kronecker-product

Is the Kronecker sum

$ A \oplus B = A \otimes I_b + I_a \otimes B$

an affine function?

Also, if so, would the following function also be an affine transformation

$f(A,B) := A \otimes M_1 + M_2 \otimes B$

for any positive-definite matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$?

Comment: What does it mean for a function of two arguments to be affine?  Are you asking if the sum is affine with respect to each input?

Comment: I'm treating (A,B) as a vector, so asking if it is affine with respect to all the elements of both A and B.